# Read uniqueidentifier field from MSSQL using python

Tags: python, sql-server, uniqueidentifier, pyodbc

I used pyodbc to access my MSSQL database.

When reading uniqueidentifier field from MSSQL, in my MacOS, I can print the correct value of udid field (e.g 4C444660-6003-13CE-CBD5-8478B3C9C984), however when I run the same code on Linux CentOS, i just see very strange string like "???E??6??????c", and the type of value is "buffer", not "str" as in MacOS.

Could you explain me why it is and how can i get correct value of uidi on linux? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In linux i use str(uuid.UUID(bytes_le=value)).upper() to get string like 4C444660-6003-13CE-CBD5-8478B3C9C984 of uniqueidentifier field

Answer (score 1):

This is a few years old, but I've had to tackle this same problem recently. My solution was to simply CAST the unique identifier as a VARCHAR, which kept my Python code nice and tidy:

```
SELECT CAST(unique_id_column AS VARCHAR(36)) AS my_id FROM...
```

Then in Python, simply output row.my_id.